# Xcode13 app icon not showing after building app

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, xcode13

I am building a react-native project for iOS RN v6.01 and initially on an older version of xcode i am able to push add the appicon on getting to xcode but with `xcode 13` i need to add the app icons before pushing. I have updated `build settings` , changed app icon sets,

**`info.plist`** all to no avail, anyone completed these task recently and now i cant deploy to test flight. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your device after installing the app.

[See more about this solution](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682648?answerId=678968022#678968022)